# Traversing HABTM relationships on ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm working on a project for my school on rails (don't worry this is not graded on code) and I'm looking for a clean way to traverse relationships in ActiveRecord.

I have ActiveRecord classes called Users, Groups and Assignments. Users and Groups have a HABTM relationship as well as Groups and Assignments. Now what I need is a User function get_group(aid) where "given a user, find its group given an assignment".

The easy route would be:

```
  def get_group(aid)
    group = nil
    groups.each { |g| group = g if g.assignment.find(aid).id == aid }
    return group
  end
```

Is there a cleaner implementation that takes advantage of the HABTM relationship between Groups and Assignments rather than just iterating? One thing I've also tried is the :include option for find(), like this:

```
  def get_group(aid)
   user.groups.find(:first, 
     :include => :assignments, 
     :conditions => ["assignments.id = ?", aid])
  end
```

But this doesn't seem to work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

First off, be careful. Since you are using `has_and_belongs_to_many` for both relationships, then there might be more than one `Group` for a given `User` and `Assignment`. So I'm going to implement a method that returns an array of `Group`s.

Second, the name of the method `User#get_group` that takes an assignment id is pretty misleading and un-Ruby-like.

Here is a clean way to get all of the common groups using Ruby's [`Array#&`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002235), the intersection operator. I gave the method a much more revealing name and put it on `Group` since it is returning `Group` instances. Note, however, that it loads `Group`s that are related to one but not the other:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :assignments
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

  # Use the array intersection operator to find all groups associated with both the User and Assignment 
  # instances that were passed in
  def self.find_all_by_user_and_assignment(user, assignment)
    user.groups & assignment.groups
  end
end
```

Then if you really needed a `User#get_groups` method, you could define it like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups

  def get_groups(assignment_id)
    Group.find_all_by_user_and_assignment(self, Assignment.find(assignment_id))
  end
end
```

Although I'd probably name it `User#groups_by_assignment_id` instead.

My `Assignment` model is simply:

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end
```